# How to align dropdown item text in a QComboBox without making it editable

Tags: c++, qt

It's unclear how to align the items of a QComboBox dropdown/popup:

- Using `text-align: left;` in QSS on the `QComboBox` or its child `QAbstractItemView` does nothing.
- There is no mention of alignment in the QComboBox documentation
- Lots of similar questions exist on SO/other forums without satisfying answers

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Qt 5.15.2 and 6.2.1:

```cpp
// class CustomComboBox : public QComboBox {...};

void CustomComboBox::setDropdownItemAlignment(Qt::Alignment alignment)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++) {
        setItemData(i, QVariant(alignment), Qt::TextAlignmentRole);
    }
}
```

And usage is

```cpp
myComboBox->setDropdownItemAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

Another possibility I haven't tested is to cast `model()` to a `QStandardItemModel*`, iterate over its rows and use `setTextAlignment`. An (untested) sketch is as follows:

```cpp
// (in a combo box subclass method)
auto stdModel = dynamic_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(model());
for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++) {
    stdModel->item(i)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
}
```